# Setting angular package development setup

Tags: angular, npm, ng-packagr

I've an angular UI component project and another angular app which is consuming it. So every time if anything is changing on that package I need to do

`npm uninstall --save @my-lib/package-one` and `npm install --save @my-lib/package-one`

Which is too time-consuming. I have tried npm link but it's not working.

Is there any other way in which I can achive this setup?

Using `ng-packagr` for packaging and angular version 5.

**EDIT 1**
Also tried to use the approach explained in this video, but unfortunately it's not working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tw8TCgeqotg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update?

Answer (score 1):

Use `npm link`:

```
cd your_package_one_dir      # go into the package directory
npm link                     # creates global link
cd your_project              # go into your project directory
npm link @my-lib/package-one # link-install the package
```

Any changes to `your_package_one_dir` will be reflected in `your_project/node_modules/@my-lib/package-one`. Note that the link should be to the package name, not the directory name for that package. See `npm link` [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Comment: Thanks the steps, I'm also doing the same steps. But getting some errors. Need one clarification whether I have `cd your_package_one_dir` or `cd your_package_one_dir/build/` dir?

Comment: Moreover, I found that there is some npm link error especially with angular project

Comment: If you are writing your package with typescript link to `build` folder. I have the same scenario, an independent module and an angular application, they work well with `npm link`.

Comment: Will try to test it again

Comment: Finally, got the `npm link` working. Everytime I need create a build folder the package inside of the project will be updated or I have manually do the `npm unlink` and `npm link`.

Comment: Great! Now accept the answer (or edit it if you made something else), or write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I was about to accept that, but still anuglar package is not working. `npm link` run successfully but at run time the lots of errors are coming. Still drilling