# How to install npm package from downloaded folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I used to install an npm project from github by doing

```
git clone http...my_project
npm install my_project
```

Instead of copying the contents of `my_project` to my local `node_modules` folder, it actually created a symlink from `node_modules/my_project` to `my_project`, then I could modify everything on my git cloned folder and it'd be on my project.

I believe this behavior changed in newer versions because it won't create the symlink anymore. It just copies the folder to `node_modules`

Is there a way to do it again?

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link .

Comment: @Vossen I forgot to mention that I know link, but it actually does a lot of things in the background and it needs root permission. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: May be try this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install "file:your/module/path" --save
```

Comment: The first time I did, it worked. Then I removed and tried again and all I get is `-- react-native-pagination@1.2.5  invalid, when it finishes. In this case, react-native-pagination is the name of my package. Do you know what that means? (I deleted everything from node_modules and the cloned repo)

Comment: Add --save (see my edited answer) the first time, delete node_modules folder and then you can type only `npm install`

Comment: it is still copying the folder. Don't know how it worked in the first time

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771724/setting-angular-package-development-setup#answer-49774330) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running:

```
git clone http...my_project
npm install my_project
```

Use this:

```
git clone http...my_project
cd my_project
npm install
```

Comment: this way it installs node_modules inside my_project